# Where can I find rodeo-inspired fonts like the one in the sample?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

What font type is used for this logo?

Answer (score 1):

As Yisela points out, 'Western' is a common term to describe the style. Specifically, these are typefaces based on display type made from wood ([wood type](http://woodtype.org/))--which was common in the US and has become part of the American west iconography. Another common association was with Circus posters. Searching for 'wood type', 'western', or 'circus poster' will likely return many results at sites like myfonts.com.

Another term to describe this particular type of style is [Tuscan](http://www.utexas.edu/cofa/rrk/gothictuscanmenu.php). Broadly speaking, it was a style of overly decorated stems and flares that was common during the wood type hey-days of the late 1800s.

A lot of wood type has been digitized. So many of the faces you'll see in different forms from different foundries.

I couldn't find an exact match, but this one is close in that is uses the rounded, flared ends:

[Hessian](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/madtype/hessian/)

FYI, if authenticity is the goal, note that you'd rarely see this type set in an arch as it is in the sample above (or below). Wood type was meant to be locked up in lines and setting in an arch, while doable, would be a pain for the typesetter.

[image]

Comment: is largely correct so I thought I'd add resources and nuance. In general wood type has many other categories like “reverse-stress/reverse-contrast slab-serifs (egyptian/egyptienne)”, “Full face/fat face” , “Tuscans” and many others. Authorities on wood type include the [Rob Roy Kelly American Wood Type Collection](http://utexas.edu/cofa/rrk/index.php) and [Hatch Show Print](http://hatchshowprint.com). [Lost Type Co-op](http://losttype.com/browse) has many donation-based wood types that are donation based for personal use. Also see [this blog](http://woodtyper.com), although it's not updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them '***Western***' fonts.

Not sure how close of a match you need, but there is a free one you can find on DaFont called [**Rio Grande**](http://www.dafont.com/rio-grande.font):

[image]

And here are some [Western inspired fonts on MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/western/fonts/).

For example **[Buffalo Circus](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/kustomtype/buffalo-circus/)**:

[image]